# read several string from a file

Tags: c, scanf

Imagine I have this .txt file:

```
HEY
What's your name
My name is xx
```

How i could make, in my C program, to scanf each line into different strings?

Because if I make

```
fscanf(myfile, "%s", string)
```

I could only scan word by word, and different lines wouldn't be recognized...

any good way I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

e.g

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char string[128];
    FILE *myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    while(1==fscanf(myfile, " %127[^\n]", string)){
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    fclose(myfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` to read lines successively from a file. However, you must know beforehand the maximum length a line can have.

```
#define MAX_LEN 100

FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
char line[MAX_LEN];

while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fp) != NULL) {
    // process line
}

fclose(fp);
```

Here, `fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fp)` means that `fgets` will read at most `MAX_LINE - 1` bytes from the stream `fp` and store them in the buffer pointed to by `line`. One byte is reserved for the null byte which `fgets` appends in the end. `fgets` will return if a newline is read which is stored into the buffer `line`. Therefore, if you want to remove the newline character from `line`, you should do the following in the above `while` loop.

```
line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';  // overwrite newline character with null byte
```